# Charts series: One column for each serie?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I have a dataTable like this one:

```
**Col1 (NUMBER) Col2 (STRING) Col3 (NUMBER)
21              A             450
12               B            600**
```

`Col1` represents days. I want to make a line chart, where the h-axis is `Col1`, and then I want to have a series for each distinct value of `Col2`. `Col3` takes the values for the v-axis. But seems that Google expect a column for each series. I should make a column for the value A, another for B, etc..

There is a way to make this I'm explaining like in Ms Excel?

Sorry for my bad English, if something is not well written tell me!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are needing to reproduce the data in a layout suitable for the chart. A quick and dirty way would be to use a spreadsheet formula:

`=QUERY(A:C;"select A, sum(C) where A is not null group by A pivot B")`

[Example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiZdNQHjqWKqdFJLeUNMNE1vWDJwMkx0aXZPekp3OEE)

...with the caveat that values in Col3 will be summed for non-unique combinations in Col1 and Col2.

Otherwise, you could use Javascript to recreate the data (which might be less dirty and less quick).

Comment: ¡Excelent! Thanks you! but I'm not using a spreadsheet for storage the data. I have the data in an object "dataTable" of Google app Script. How can I apply this the same? Thanks you a lot!

Comment: Oh I see, sorry. How are you constructing your object in the first place?